# Spring Boot doesnt return template in Post Mapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I hope some of you have an idea about this. I'm still new to Spring but till this point I could figured out every problem myself. I'm using also Thymeleaf for the templates.
In the Controller the function for @GetMapping works as intended, but the @PostMapping function doesnt return the template which I specified in the return parameter and so the browser shows the wrong page.
The @PostMapping function gets triggered by the ajax statement in the html script.

I get no errors or warnings on server side as well as on client side. So I have no idea were the spot the mistake.

Hope some of you can spot the mistake. Thanks in advance anyway.

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class SpringController {


@RequestMapping(value="/tank", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadData(Model model){

    Tankstelle[] data = TankerAPI.getTankData(lat, lng, 5, sort, type);

    model.addAllAttributes(convertdata("name", data));
    model.addAllAttributes(convertdata("dist", data));
    model.addAllAttributes(convertdata("price", data));

    return "home";
}



@RequestMapping(value = "/tank", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getChangedData(@RequestBody JSONObject incomingjson) {

    lat = Float.parseFloat(incomingjson.get("lat").toString());
    lng = Float.parseFloat(incomingjson.get("lng").toString());
    BigDecimal biglat = new BigDecimal(lat).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal biglng = new BigDecimal(lng).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    lat = biglat.floatValue();
    lng = biglng.floatValue();

    sort = "price"; //for seeing a difference

    System.out.println(incomingjson.get("lat")+" "+incomingjson.get("lng"));

    return "test";   //here it should return the template "test" but it return "home"


}
```

home.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>guenstigertanken.de</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>...
    </style>


</head>
<body onload="getLocation()">
    <div class="ueberschriftbox"></div>
   <h2 class="header">guenstigertanken.de</h2>
    <h2 class="subheader">Wir finden die günstigsten Spritpreise für Sie</h2>
    <div class="backrounding">    

        <div class="steuerelementebox"></div>
        <div class="steuerelementespritsorteueberschrift">
                <h2>Spritsorte</h2>
            <label class="container1">Super E5
              <input type="radio" id="E5" name="radio1" onclick="autoSubmit()">
              <span class="checkmark1"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="container1">Super E10
              <input type="radio" id="E10" name="radio1" onclick="autoSubmit()">
              <span class="checkmark1"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="container1">Diesel
              <input type="radio" id="Diesel" name="radio1" onclick="autoSubmit()">
              <span class="checkmark1"></span>
            </label> 
        </div> 

            <div class="steuerelementesortierennachueberschrift">
                <h2>Sortieren nach</h2>
                <label class="container2">Preis aufsteigend
                  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio2" onclick="autoSubmit()">
                  <span class="checkmark2"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container2">Preis absteigend
                  <input type="radio" name="radio2" onclick="autoSubmit()">
                  <span class="checkmark2"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container2">Distanz aufsteigend
                  <input type="radio" name="radio2" onclick="autoSubmit()">
                  <span class="checkmark2"></span>
                </label> <label class="container2">Distanz absteigend
                  <input type="radio" name="radio2" onclick="autoSubmit()">
                  <span class="checkmark2"></span>
                </label>
                 <label class="container2" id="alph">Name alphabetisch
                  <input type="radio" name="radio2" onclick="autoSubmit()">
                  <span class="checkmark2"></span>
                </label>
            </div>       
        <div class="buttonsbox"></div>
        <div class="tabellenbox"></div>
        <div class="ueberuns">
            <p>Über uns</p>  
        </div>
        <div class="agb">
            <p>AGB</p>  
        </div>
        <div class="datenschutz">
            <p>Datenschutz</p>  
        </div>
        <div class="impressum">
            <p>Impressum</p>  
        </div>
        <div class="left show">
            <table id="datatable">
                <thead>
                <tr>    <th>Name</th>   <th>Entfernung</th>     <th>Preis</th>  <th>Favorit</th> </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr> <td th:text="${name1}">AGIP</td> <td th:text="${dist1}">7km</td> <td th:text="${price1}">1,20€</td> <td><input type="checkbox"></td> </tr>
                <tr> <td th:text="${name2}">Aral</td> <td th:text="${dist2}">12km</td> <td th:text="${price2}">1,23€</td> <td><input type="checkbox"></td>  </tr>
                <tr> <td th:text="${name3}">Esso</td> <td th:text="${dist3}">2km</td> <td th:text="${price3}">1,25€</td> <td><input type="checkbox"></td> </tr>
                <tr> <td th:text="${name4}">Esso</td> <td th:text="${dist4}">10km</td> <td th:text="${price4}">1,25€</td> <td><input type="checkbox"></td> </tr>
                <tr> <td th:text="${name5}">Esso</td> <td th:text="${dist5}">5km</td> <td th:text="${price5}">1,25€</td> <td><input type="checkbox"></td> </tr>
                <tr> <td th:text="${name6}">BP</td> <td th:text="${dist6}">13km</td> <td th:text="${price6}">1,35€</td> <td><input type="checkbox"></td> </tr>
                <tr> <td th:text="${name7}">BP</td> <td th:text="${dist7}">13km</td> <td th:text="${price7}">1,35€</td> <td><input type="checkbox"></td> </tr>
                <tr> <td th:text="${name8}">BP</td> <td th:text="${dist8}">13km</td> <td th:text="${price8}">1,35€</td> <td><input type="checkbox"></td> </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div> 
  </div>
   <a class="cssbuttonfavoriten" href="test.html">Favoriten></a>
   <a class="cssbuttonleaderboard" href="test.html">Leaderboard></a>
   <a class="cssbuttonstatistiken" href="test.html">Statistiken></a>



    <script>

        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            } else {

            }

        }

        function showPosition(position) {

            var posdata = '{"lat":"'+position.coords.latitude+'","lng":"'+position.coords.longitude+'","typeselect":"'+type+'"}';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/tank',
                data: JSON.stringify(posdata),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                traditional: true,
                success: function(posdata) {

                    //alert("ajax success: refresh page to sort after price[prob current setting]")
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("ajax error")
                }
            });
        }


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make any request through ajax you just receive corresponding response in your callback function:

```
                success: function(posdata) {

                //alert("ajax success: refresh page to sort after price[prob current setting]")
            },
```

So browser will not show you a new template page. Your page is in "postdata" response

Comment: thanks, i'm absolute beginner to javascript, how do i change this, that its the not the posdata response?

Comment: function() or function(response) doesn't work either

Comment: When you send ajax request that means that your code handles any response. Even if you use function() without arguments it doesn't mean that browser will update page. I'm not sure that there is any way force browser to handle that response and render a web page